# Adding Xunit for asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net, testing, xunit

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?
I have Asp.net core webb application and use VS Code, I tried to add xunit directory for testing my application but finally I got this:

[image]

My application cannot see Xunit even when I 'using' it

My algorithm of adding xunit:

> 1. Manually create directory UnitTests
> 2. Use in command line command 'dotnet new xunit'

And finally I got mistake.

Comment: what is your environment? if you're using .net core of version < 2.0 then you have to call `dotnet restore` manually in newly created xunit project

Answer (score 0):

Dit you add the required NuGet packages? Should be present in the project file and look something like:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
```